# Cant find solution: load images to div based on page location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i need a solution to a problem i have a nav bar and in that nav there is a div (A) to the far right, that stays in one place because the nav is fixed at the top. In the body of the page there is 6 sections that are 1200px tall divs and i would like to load a different image to the div (A) in question when the user scrolls down from one section to another.

I have looked at a ton of possible solutions but nothing has worked. Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: Let's see page markup first and your own code if any.

Comment: but that link will not give the full effect that the page has now, thats the only thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found the answer i was looking for, i feel bad now but the only think that was wrong was my file path. IDK why but that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what source you are trying to place into each div, you can use `.scrollTop()` in jQuery to achieve that effect. Once the value returned from `.scrollTop()` is `x`, change the `src` attribute of the div.

Placewhatever source you want loaded into each of your "if statments" to change your nav img and play around with the `.scrollTop()` number to achieve the desired effect.

[.scroll() event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)

I don't have access to jsbin or the like at work but I tested the below in the code snippet feature. Just make sure the page actually scrolls to test it.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#navImg').html(top);
    if (top > 100) {
       $('#botImg').attr('src', 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/dog/dog1.jpg');
    }
    if (top < 100) {
       $('#botImg').attr('src', 'http://davidfeldmanshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/dogs-wallpaper.jpg');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#nav {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  }

#navImg {
  height:30px;
  width: 30px;
  top:15px;
  left:15px;
  position:fixed;
  background:green;
  }

#bottom {
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  height:1200px;
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  }

#botImg {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='nav'><div id='navImg'></div></div>

<div id='bottom'><img id='botImg' src='http://davidfeldmanshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/dogs-wallpaper.jpg' /></div>
```

Comment: i really wish that would work but i need to use a png. image not a color, and the png.'s i have are not working.

Comment: Edited answer. Run the snippet above, made it work with imgs instead of background colors